# Question about logs

Tags: roots

For what values of $k$ will $kx^2 = \log(x)$ have exactly $1$ solution?

Received this question from a friend who was asked this in an interview. I thought the answer was $k=0$ but this was wrong.

Comment: Think of the graphs. For example, when k is negative there is always exactly one solution because the parabola must intersect the graph of log.

Comment: In complex numbers, there are infinitely many solutions (at least if you allow all branches of log) unless $k=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We can distiguish three cases

- for $k=0$ we have exactly one solution for $x=1$
- for $k<0$ we have alway one intersection, it can be proved by studing sign and monoticity of the function $f(x)=\log x -kx^2$
- for $k>0$ we have one intersection when $\log x$ and $kx^2$ are tangent

Indeed since for k=0 we have one intersection point and for $k=1$ we have that

- $x^2>x-1\ge \log x$

there exists an intermediate value for $k$ such that the two curves are tangent.

The condition of tangency at $(x_0,y_0)$ can be expressed by

- tangent for $\log x$: $y-\log x_0=\frac1{x_0}(x-x_0)$
- tangent for $kx^2$: $y-kx_0^2=2kx_0(x-x_0)$

and thus we must have

- $\frac1{x_0}=2kx_0\implies k=\frac1{2x_0^2}$
- $\log x_0=kx_0^2=\frac12\implies x_0=\sqrt e \quad k=\frac1{2e}$

Thus for $k>0$ $\log x=kx^2$ has exactly one solution for $k=\frac1{2e}$ with tangent point at $(\sqrt e,\frac12)$.

[Plot for the tangency case k>0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%20x%3D%20x%5E2%2F(2e))

Comment: how do you find the intersection point for $k>0$? why must they be tangent?

Comment: @user534507 I'll add some detail

Answer (score 2):

There is one $k$ for which the two (real) curves touch. It is determined by the condition that at the point $x_0$ where $kx_0^2=\ln x_0$, the slopes $2kx_0$ and $\frac1{x_0}$ are the same - which means that we must have $\ln x_0=kx_0^2=\frac12$, $x_0=\sqrt e$ and ultimately $$k=\frac 1{2e}.$$
As said, the $k$ will leead to a single touching point between the curves.
For any $k>\frac1{2e}$, there will be no intersection at all.
For any $k$ with $0<k<\frac1{2e}$, the will be two intesections (because the paraola eventually wins over the log).
But for $$k\le 0,$$ we will have exactly one intersection as well.

Comment: You lost me after the slopes bit. Where is $\sqrt{e}$ coming from?